# Detect invalid Google Maps API key format without calling API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I maintain some plugins that allow developers to use the Google Maps javascript API. It is the developer's responsibility to supply their API Key when they build apps using my plugins.

In my sample code and applications where the key must be entered, I put in examples like "`(enter your API key here)`" or "`API_KEY`" because these are checked into the publicly accessible source code repository. At the moment, my plugin simply passes this string to the Google Maps API "as is". The only validation I do is to test that some value has been entered.

I want a **simple** test that will (with reasonable accuracy) determine whether a given string is NOT a real Google Maps API key. So far I haven't seen any documentation from Google indicating what to expect the string to look like.

I don't care if my test sometimes gets false positives, because the developer will get a Google Map error at runtime if they don't have a valid key. I do care about false negatives, however; if they supply a valid Google Maps API key, but my code falsely blocks it as "invalid", that would be a failure on my part.

All the valid Google Maps API keys I've seen seem to be exactly 39 characters long, consisting of the characters `AI` followed by 37 alphanumeric characters or dashes, e.g.:

```
AIjlSyEI1n03b7-this-is-fake-5tHcDxy1RnI
```

**Would I run the risk of penalising anyone if I simply tested that the candidate key is at least 39 characters long?**

**What if I tested that the first two characters are `AI`?**

**What if I checked for the existence of characters like `(`, `)`, or `_`?**

(if you have seen a valid Google Maps API key that does not conform to the above "rules" I've made up, could you comment? That would help to invalidate my hypothesis.)

(as MrUpsidown pointed out, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors) does not state any rules one way or another - so the only **perfect** method would be to call the API - but in my case I want code that will run in isolation on the server side)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors

Comment: I have read that document in detail and it does not provide the info I asked for. Please read my question. I cannot assume that the user of my plugin has access at the server side to call the Google Maps API to validate the key. I just want a simple string test.

Comment: There is no other documented way.

Comment: Good question. I'll give you an answer tomorrow afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on string validation because the way API keys are formatted could always change and like you said, it would give a bad customer experience to display an error message for a valid API key. This is a potentially useful feature to get though so I recommend you file a feature request in [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). For now all you can do is call the API to [catch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors) any errors should the request fail like MrUpsidown suggested.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've raised it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155851780

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)